# Duplicate notifications

Tags: support, ios-app

I receive every push notification from the iOS app twice on iPhone. The second comes immediately after the first. This happens every single time.

I also have the app installed on an iPad and signed in to the same account - could this be a possible cause?

- App Version: 1.4.0
- Device: iPhone7,2
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: This happened before recently and we're trying to determine if it's an Apple bug.  We have four entries for your account in the database, each with a unique device identifier.  Do you have multiple devices with the app installed, or have you uninstalled and reinstalled the app?

Comment: I currently have it installed only one device but I did have it installed on another simultaneously recently. I wipe my devices fairly often due to betas etc. so I will have installed more than once on the same device. I haven't installed on four separate devices but I believe iOS device IDs are non-permanent. The four IDs may be due to factory resetting my two devices.

Comment: I have cleared all tokens except for your most recently used.  I'm classifying this one as an anomaly for the moment due to beta / wiping / etc.

Comment: @Geoff but if the device changed identifier, doesn't it explain the duplicate notifications?

Comment: That seems to working @GeoffDalgas. I'll report back if it happens again. Thanks

Comment: @ShadowWizard We appear to be having a nightmare scenario where iOS is issuing a new push tokens in certain scenarios without invalidating the old ones.  Logically speaking, if we were to wipe a device, the old notifications tokens should be no good, especially after a new one is issued.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840916/receiving-duplicate-push-notification-ios9

Comment: @BrianNickel so to conclude, [tag:status-apple-fault]? ;-)

Comment: @Brian can you please post an answer summing up the comments, including Geoff's? This appears to [happen to others as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276339/ios-app-notification-pushed-twice).

Comment: I am still getting this issue on my iPhone 5S, iOS 9.3.1, any update? Yes did Uninstall and Install app multiple time. and I have only this device.