# iOS app notification pushed twice

Tags: support, ios-app

Now a days in iOS stack exchange app I'm getting the same notification twice.

[image]

- My device is iPhone 5 with iOS 9.2.1.
- Stack Exchange App version is 1.4.3.7

Is this problem with my mobile?

Comment: You get this fot every notification?

Comment: Yes. Even the notification for your msg it happend.

Comment: I see. I remember a similar bug reported before, will try finding it soon.

Comment: Found it, look at the comments in the duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks.